# How to get the values from string to textview? in Android

Tags: android

In my application I want to display some items in a list, I kept all items in String array and brought by using code

```
 String[] activities = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Contents);
```

Now my task is assign these string array values to my `TextView`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: All the values to a single TextView or to the textview in the list??

Comment: do you want to display Array in to TextView ?

Comment: TextView in a List, I am using BaseAdapter for this, but I am unable to get the values if I use the code Textview.setText(activities[position])

Comment: Even I want to add an Imageview to my List, If I use ArrayAdapetr I cant add both Textview and Imageview right?

Comment: try this http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/07/custom-list-view.html just a sample that may help you to work according to your requirement

Comment: I am very new to here, Can you tell me how to post LogCat please?

Comment: well i am not sure how to do it but i would capture it and paste it here.

Comment: What's the error? try to give the complete line

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, activities);
mylistView.setAdapter(aa);
```

Answer (score 0):

> In MainActivity.class

```
String[] activities = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Contents);
List<RowItem> rowItems;
In onCreate(){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(layoutname);
rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
RowItem item = new RowItem(activities[i]);
rowItems.add(item);
}
listView = (ListView) findViewById(id of ListView);
CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, rowItems);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

> In RowItem class

```
public class RowItem {
 private String activities;
public RowItem(String activities {
this.activities = activities;
}
public String getActivities() {
return activities;
}
public void setactivities(String activities) {
this.activities = activities;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
return activities;
}
}
```

> In CustomBaseAdapter class

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<RowItem> rowItems;
public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> items) {
this.context = context;
this.rowItems = items;
}

private class ViewHolder {
TextView txtActivities;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.activities);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) getItem(position);


        holder.txtActivites.setText(rowItem.getActivity());


        return convertView;
    }
 }
```